# Summing up multiple class Def function to get total amount in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've gone through questions relating to my question, but none is pointing to what I've in mind. I've different class model, with def functions. I can achieve the total amount for each model, but what I want to achieve is, after getting the total amount for each model, how can I sum to models together, to get my total amount for all the models. Below are my code

```
class HomeOrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(HomeItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.home_price
        
    def get_total_discount_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.home_discount_price

    
    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.home_discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discount_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()


class HomeOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_items = models.ManyToManyField(HomeOrderItem)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_created = models.DateTimeField()
    home_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total_everything(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.home_items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total

class MenOrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    men_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MenItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.men_price
        
    def get_total_discount_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.men_discount_price

    
    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.men_discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discount_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()


class MenOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    men_items = models.ManyToManyField(MenOrderItem)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_created = models.DateTimeField()
    men_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total_men_everything(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.men_items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total
```

I want to be able to add up the `def get_total_everything() + def get_total_men_everything ()` to get my final amount

Answer (score 1):

You can use @staticmethod decorator above these functions, import the models on the views then You can call it like this:
`sum = HomeOrderItem.get_total_item_price() + HomeOrderItem.get_total_discount_price() + ...etc` , You can list all the functions you want.

Comment: thanks very much for response, I think I'm very close to achieving what I've in mind, all thanks to you. But when I did as you instructed, I get an error ```get_total_everything()``` missing 1 required positional argument "self". I think this is as a result of ```get_total_everything(self)``` in my models. When I try to have the self i.e ```total_total(user,self)``` I still get an error.. thanks for your time

Comment: In these functions are you trying to have total per objects? or whole model?

Comment: I'm trying to add just the ```def get_total_everything``` and ```def get_total_home_everything``` in the ```HomeOrder(models.Model)``` and ```MenOrder(models.Model)``` respectively... Thanks

Comment: if I understand you well , you need to have object first ex: Obj = HomeOrder.objects.get(id=1) then call it as Obj.get_total_everything, + change @ staticmethod to @ property

Comment: sorry to say this, but I think your getting my question wrong. From the code above, I've an idea in my head, something like ```sum=Home order.get_total_everything() + MenOrder.order.get_men_total_everything()```. That way, I Will be able to add the total of the home order and men order... Sorry for the stress, I'm grateful